# Gerrit Code Review: Can not find "Review" and "Abandon Change" button after system upgrading

Tags: gerrit

After upgrading Gerrit from 2.7 to 2.12, "Review" and "Abandon Change" button disappeared.

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Gerrit 2.12.x these buttons are named as follow:

```
Review         => Reply...
Abandon Change => Abandon
```

If you're not able to see them it's good to check your permissions.

Answer (score 0):

1.check your login status

2.check your permissions